# How do I filter query objects (DecimalFIeld) by value range in Django?

Tags: django, django-models

I've a Django model with a [`DecimalField`](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.0/ref/models/fields/#decimalfield).

```py
class SomeModel(models.Model):
    decimal_field = models.DecimalField()
```

I'd like to get all model instances which have a field value in the range of e.g. `5.0` and `10.0`. I've read the [Django docs section about queries](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.0/topics/db/queries/) but I did not find a solution. How do I have to write the query `SomeModel.objects.filter(?)` ?

Comment: Did you get the answer on this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use [the range field lookup](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.0/ref/models/querysets/#range).

```
SomeModel.objects.filter(decimal_field__range=(lower_limit, upper_limit))
```

Comment: Do you know if range field has advantages over the solution above?

Comment: @thinwybk - Seems to me you’re less likely to make a mistake and that it’s more readable. It also produces different sql on at least some databases, so it may run quicker on those but it might just be syntactic sugar.

Comment: I think it's the better solution. Thx.

Answer (score 2):

You should use the __gt __gte __lt __lte [field lookups](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.0/ref/models/querysets/), corresponding to greater, than greater than or equal, less than, less than or equal, so the query you want to do should look like:

```
SomeModel.objects.filter(decimal_field__gte=lower_limit, decimal_field__lte=upper_limit)
```